# c# - HttpClient with HttpClientHandler cancellation not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I am facing an issue with HttpClient (.NETStandard v2.1, System.Net.Http, targeting mono runtime). I want to set timeout for `HttpClient` per request by passing a `CancellationToken` in `SendAsync`.

It is working properly when using the parameterless constructor of `HttpClient`, but it is ignored when passing to the `HttpClient` constructor an instance of `HttpClientHandler`. The operation is cancelled after 75 secs.

To illustrate:

```cs
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Send()
{
    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("someURL"));
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler{ CookieContainer = new CookieContainer() };  
    /* var client = new HttpClient(); <--- This is working */          
    var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    cts.Token.Register(() => Debug.WriteLine("TASK CANCELLED"));
    return await client.SendAsync(req, cts.Token);
}
```

After 5 secs the debug output writes "TASK CANCELLED" but the `SendAsync` continues for a total of 75 secs. If i use the parameterless constructor the `SendAsync` cancels after 5 secs.

I need the `HttpClientHandler` to use the `CookieContainer` property.
What am i missing here?

---

**EDIT**

After further investigation and the hints of @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen i figured out the following:

1. .NET Core 3 runtime

   - If the url is not reachable or internet connection is down the `HttpClient` throws `HttpRequestException` after 3 secs
   - Otherwise it cancels as expected after 5 secs
2. Mono runtime (Xamarin.Forms project)

   - If the url is not reachable or internet connection is down the `HttpClient` throws `OperationCanceledException` after 75 secs
   - Otherwise it cancels as expected after 5 secs

Maybe it is related to [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5941/system-net-http-httpclient-timeout-seems-to-be-ignored).

Still an open issue though...

Comment: A simple test I did in LINQPad 6 using .NET Core 3 worked with your code, was cancelled after 5 seconds. Which runtime are you running this in?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen This is located inside a .NETStandard v2.1 class that is referenced from a Xamarin.Forms project.

Comment: .NET Standard is not a runtime, you could run your code on both .NET Framework and .NET Core, but Xamarin is helpful. It means you're running on the mono runtime.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen What do you think about this behavior? Might it be due to the mono runtime, if it works properly in .NET Core?

Comment: @ΓαβριήλΣαμώλης You couls sharing your solution in answer and mark it. Thank you~

Comment: @WendyZang I think there must be an issue with the `HttpClient` and the mono runtime. As a mediocre workaround i used this plugin [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Connectivity/) which offers a property called `IsRemoteReachable` where the Android platform implementation of it creates a new `Socket` connection to the specified `url` with a `timeout`, and i use it prior to `http requests` with timeout 1000ms to specify the reachability. I do not consider this a solution, still searching for something more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method I found was using the [Polly library](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) and wrapping the methods that would not honor the `CancellationToken`. You don't even need a `CancellationToken`. Example:

```
var policy = Policy.TimeoutAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000),
    TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic,
    (context, timespan, task) => throw new Exception("Cannot connect to server."));

await policy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(...);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    ...
});
```

Comment: Yes, you **do** need the `CancellationToken`. Your setup will not cancel the request after 3 seconds. In order to use [optimistic timeout](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#optimistic-timeout) you need to use the `ExecuteAsync` like this: `.ExecuteAsync(async ct =>  { ... httpClient.PostAsync(..., ct); ... }, CancellationToken.None);`